# Image not showing in JQuery / HTML

Tags: jquery, html, image

So I am new to JQuery and HTML and I got the `Uncaught ReferenceError: img is not defined` error in the console. I fixed that, and it runs, but now it doesn't display the img... Any suggestions? My project should be a slide show so when you click on the next button it goes to the next picture. I haven't added in all of the photos yet because I wanted to get this working first, but there will be 4 in total. Also, I'm use the editor on Khan Academy, so if some of the variables are weird (such as var) that's why.

Here is my body and script code. Thanks for the help!

```
<body>

<br>
<img>
<button type="button" id="next">Next ➡</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script> //access to jQuery library
<script>
var photo=function(nums){
    console.log("nums "+nums);//checking to see if the right number was received from the function
    if (nums===1){
        $("img")//I think the problem is here
            .css("src","https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/food/mushroom.png")//photo on khan academy
            .css("width","400")
            .css("alt","Mushrooms");
    } else if (nums===2){
        $("img")
            .css("src","https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/food/coffee-beans.png") //photo on khan academy
            .css("width","400")
            .css("alt","Coffee Beans");
    }  
    $("img").slideDown(1000);
}

$("img").hide();

$("#next").on("click", function() {
        var num = 0;
        if(num < 4){
            num++;
        }else{
            num = 1;
        }
        console.log("num "+num);//checking to see if the right number was sent to the function
        photo(num);
    });


</script>
</body>
```

Comment: `src` and `alt` are no css attributes. These are html attributes... Try switching from `.css`  to `.attr`

Comment: there are two bugs one for ``attr`` and one for ``var num``

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `attr()` function

Like that

```
        $("img")
            .attr("src","https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/food/mushroom.png")//photo on khan academy
            .attr("width","400")
            .attr("alt","Mushrooms");
```

Answer (score 0):

`src` and `alt` aren't *CSS* properties.  They're *HTML* properties (or attributes).  So this isn't going to do anything observable:

```
.css("src","https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/food/mushroom.png")
```

but this will:

```
.attr("src","https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/food/mushroom.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set HTML attributes with jQuery's `css()` function which will not work, you need to use `attr()`, and `width()`:

```
$("img")
    .attr("src","https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/food/mushroom.png")//photo on khan academy        
    .attr("alt","Mushrooms")
    .width("400px");
```

Answer (score 0):

### Your have Two problems in your code.

---

Syntax Error

```
var photo=function(nums){
console.log("nums "+nums);//checking to see if the right number was received from the function
if (nums===1){
    $("img")//I think the problem is here
        .attr("src","https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/food/mushroom.png")//photo on khan academy
        .css("width","400")
        .attr("alt","Mushrooms");
} else if (nums===2){
    $("img")
        .attr("src","https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/food/coffee-beans.png") //photo on khan academy
        .css("width","400")
        .attr("alt","Coffee Beans");
}  
$("img").slideDown(1000);
}
```

Note: `css` replaced with `attr` as `src` and `alt` are not css actions

---

Logical Error

```
var num = 0;
$("#next").on("click", function() {
    if(num < 4){
        num++;
    }else{
        num = 1;
    }
    console.log("num "+num);//checking to see if the right number was sent to the function
    photo(num);
});
```

Note: Placed `var num = 0` out of the function because in function it'll reset to 0 every time you click next